# Buffer Overrun using Mysql Connector c++

Tags: c++, database, mysql

I'm having a few issues executing sql statements in c++ using the connector.

Any hints or ideas are welcome.

NB: Mysql Connector c++ 1.05

I have these defined in the class header:

```
sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    sql::PreparedStatement *prep_stmt;
```

And the functional code in the .cpp file:

```
driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver -> connect(url, user, pass);
    //con -> setAutoCommit(0);
    cout << "\nConnection OK!";
    cout << "\nDatabase connection\'s autocommit mode = " << con -> getAutoCommit() << endl;
    con -> setSchema(database);
    prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tbl_stats;");
        res = prep_stmt->executeQuery(); //BREAKS HERE
```

The last line breaks with a buffer overrun.

If i step into the line during debug, it occasionally reports that there is no source file, however when it does, it allows you to single step a section of ASM.

this code bellow causes a similar error:

```
stmt = con->createStatement();
stmt->execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_stats;"); //BREAK HERE
```

Is there any way to debug this kind of error?
Has anyone seen this before?

is there any better/simpler ways of c++ mysql interaction

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Unless the API (which I'm not familar with) uses exceptions, in all cases you should be checking if the previous API call has succeeded before you call the next one.

Comment: Forgive my nativity but is this not implied by returning from the call without breaking? How would I implement a check?

Comment: @Luke: No need to ask forgiveness for being born.  8vD

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API either, but from an example I found it appears there should be an exception if there's an error: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

Comment: @Luke, what do the docs say happens if the calls to get_driver__instance or connect fail?  If they throw then you need to deal with the exception.  If they return an error code or more likely in this case null, then you need to check for that.  In the above code, if connect returns null then you've got some undefined behaviour which could explain your error

Comment: @Fred that exact example and a few others, if u run that code it breaks on:

res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");




ASM manual debug trace for the original code:

Comment: 10052424  call        sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet::MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet (10002B44h)
10002B44  jmp         sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet::MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet (10056A10h)
10056B03  call        sql::mysql::MySQL_ResultBind::bindResult (10001E01h) 
10001E01  jmp         sql::mysql::MySQL_ResultBind::bindResult (10061F50h)
100622AA  call        sql::mysql::util::throwSQLException (100020A9h) 

as you can see it looks like its throwing one, but its not quite getting there before the buffer overrun

Comment: @Glen: if the driver instance fails it throws and after checking the command is assigning a value to it.

The driver is being used to connect to the database, which is fine (after checking in netstat) so if it was null this would not work

Comment: After a bunch of messing around getting the API installed, it works just fine for me.  What environment are you on?  Did you install MySQL Connector binaries or build from source?

Comment: Thanks Fred, i appreciate your effort at least i know its a lib issue.

I installed then referenced the libs, however i did have some issues installing the bits and pieces.

Thanks again.